# I am having dificulties creating a react project and i dont know what i am doing wrong

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, command-prompt

node version: v12.18.3
npm version: 6.14.6
yarn version: 1.22.4

I have already tried to create the project using npm and yarn, but these two ways are doing the same thing.
they only create the directory node-modules, the packege.json, and the yarn.lock
I have tried to reinstall everything but it didn't work out.
this is what appears in the PowerShell:

`````
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Installed "create-react-app@3.4.1" with binaries:
      - create-react-app

Creating a new React app in C:\nlw\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

   

yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 15 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-scripts@3.4.1
└─ react@16.13.1
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/helper-member-expression-to-functions@7.11.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@7.10.4
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.11.0
├─ @babel/preset-typescript@7.9.0
├─ babel-preset-react-app@9.1.2
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1
├─ react-dev-utils@10.2.1
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-error-overlay@6.0.7
├─ react-scripts@3.4.1
├─ react@16.13.1
└─ scheduler@0.19.1
Done in 63.49s.````
`````

Comment: what was the commands with npm and yarn did you try to create the react project? Did you already try it with "npx create-react-app my-app" ?

Comment: yes, I tried this command and the same thing happened

Comment: ´these commands should install the src directory right?

Comment: try to clean npm (npm cache clean --force) before run the create command with npx.

Comment: the same thing happened, only the "node modules",  "package.json" and the yarn.lock files were created

Comment: i will try to install the other files manually